# Retrieve custom error Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I don't know how to show custom messages on my form using jquery. I'm using Yii and I call an action to update my database. What I want to do is show some error messages in the case that something's wrong in the form.

The first action is this:

```
if($this->id == "survey") { // Esta condicición es por si se trata de mail, sms, qr o tpe (queda pendiente el callback) ?>
        x$("input#surveysubmit").click(function() {
            var data = serialize(document.getElementById("token-form")); 
            if(!checkRequiredBeforeSubmit(data)) return;
            x$().xhr('<?php echo $this->createUrl('survey/index', array('id'=>$model->skey)); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: urlstringserialize(serialize(document.getElementById("token-form"))),
                callback: function() {respOK(this.responseText);}
            });
        });
```

As you could see this is calling survey/index. Index is a controller action that finally redirects to Token/Fill that does this:

```
public function actionFill($id, $agent = '') {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
        // Ñapa-parche para seleccionables
        $index = 0;
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if(preg_match('/^'.$key.'/', $value)) {
                $_POST[$value] = 1;
                $BAD = array($key, $value);
                $_POST = array_diff($_POST, $BAD);
                $index++;
            }
        }

        $requiredok = $this->controlRequiredValues($model, $model->transformSurveyRawData($_POST));
        if ($requiredok == '') {
            $isok = $model->createAnswersForToken($model->transformSurveyRawData($_POST));
            if ($isok) {
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

controlRequiredValues is the function to control errors:

```
public function controlRequiredValues($model, $answers) {
    //Recupero Oleada
    $wave = $model->wave;
    //Recupero Campaña/Centro
    $campaignCenter = $wave->campaignCenter;
    //Recupero Campaña
    $campaign = $campaignCenter->campaign;
    //Recupero Template
    $template = $campaign->template;
    //Recupero Preguntas del template
    $questions = $campaignCenter->campaign->template->questions;
    //Primero miro si las answers que me vienen en la encuesta son required o no
    foreach($answers['answers'] as $key=>$qvalue) {
        //Si existe la pregunta para la respueta que me han enviado, es una pregunta requerida y su valor es nulo
        $question = Question::model()->findByPk($key);
        if (isset($question) && $question->required == 1 && $qvalue = ""){
            $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
            return json_encode($arr);
        }
        //Si no, hay que mirar si tiene condicional relacionado con otra pregunta
        else{
            $questioncondition = QuestionCondition::model()->find('question_id=:qid0 AND reqshow=:rs0', array('qid0'=>$question->id, 'rs0'=>'req'));
            if (isset($questioncondition)){
                if (array_key_exists($questioncondition->question_id_dep, $answers['answers'])) {
                    $cond = $qvalue. " " . $questioncondition->operator . " " . $questioncondition->rvalue;
                    if (!$cond){
                        $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                        return json_encode($arr);
                    }
                } else {
                    $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                    echo json_encode($arr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Ahora miramos en las preguntas del template.
    $questions = $template->questions;

    foreach($questions as $question) {
        //Si en el template dice que la pregunta es required

        if (isset($question) && $question->required == 1) {
            //Puede que no exista en el array de respuestas o si existe que esté en blanco, en cuyo caso mostraremos error.
            if(array_key_exists($question->id, $answers['answers'])) {
                $clave = array_search('', $answers['answers']);
                if (isset($clave)){
                    $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                    return json_encode($arr);
                } else {
                    $questioncondition = QuestionCondition::model()->find('question_id=:qid0 AND reqshow=:rs0', array('qid0'=>$question->id, 'rs0'=>'req'));
                    if (isset($questioncondition)){
                        if (array_key_exists($questioncondition->question_id_dep, $answers['answers'])) {
                            $cond = $qvalue. " " . $questioncondition->operator . " " . $questioncondition->rvalue;
                            if (!$cond){
                                $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                                return json_encode($arr);
                            }
                        } else {
                            $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                            return json_encode($arr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                return json_encode($arr);
            }
        } else {
            $questioncondition = QuestionCondition::model()->find('question_id=:qid0 AND reqshow=:rs0', array('qid0'=>$question->id, 'rs0'=>'req'));
            if (isset($questioncondition)){
                if (array_key_exists($questioncondition->question_id_dep, $answers['answers'])) {
                    $cond = $qvalue. " " . $questioncondition->operator . " " . $questioncondition->rvalue;
                    if (!$cond){
                        $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                        return json_encode($arr);
                    }
                } else {
                    $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                    return json_encode($arr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is show these errors to end users.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the default error action with flash messages.

```
public function actionError() {
    if ($error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) {
        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $error['message']);
        else {
            $this->render('error', $error);
            //or
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $error['message']);
        }
    }
}
```

And in `config/main.php` in components array add:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
),
```

Then just throw a new base/custom exception when you want/need to.

More on this here: [error handling](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error) and here: [flash messages](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/)

---

**EDIT:**

---

After implementing this you can throw a CException when ever you need, not just for this specific request.
Alternatively you can implement this and keep the controlRequiredValues() as is and change this:

```
if ($requiredok == '') {
    $isok = $model->createAnswersForToken($model->transformSurveyRawData($_POST));
    if ($isok) {
        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    }
}
```

To this:

```
$isok = $model->createAnswersForToken($model->transformSurveyRawData($_POST));
if ($isok) {
     $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id, 'error' => $requiredok));
}
```

So, remove the if statement checking if `$requiredok` is empty and pass it to the view, then in view check if it's empty and if it's not throw a [CDbException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbException).

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar B. This actionError function must be instead of: $arr = array('error' => $question->id. " is required");
                        return json_encode($arr); isn't it?

Comment: You implement actionError() in SiteController, and in config set it as the default(global) error handler. Instead of `return json_encode($arr);` and `echo json_encode($arr);` you throw a new exception like this:`throw new CDbException('Message here');` or for Http `throw new CHttpException($status, 'Message here');`. In CDbException error code is optional but for CHttpException it is required. I'll update my answer with more detail.

Comment: I can't change the $requiredok code because I have to avoid to createanswers if any error.